# Connecting QPushButon to a method in another class in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qpushbutton

I am trying to connect a `QPushButton` created in class `A` with a method created in class `B` . This is my code:

```
class A(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
    #A lot of stuff in here

  def Button(self):
    self.btn = QPushButton()
    self.connect(self.btn, SIGNAL("clicked()"), B().method_1)


class B(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    #Another stuff in here too

  def method_1(self):
    pass
```

But, it is not working. I read this post:

[Send and receive signals from another class pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806921/send-and-receive-signals-from-another-class-pyqt)

and it says that I can do it creating a `pyqtSignal`. Is there another way to do this? I mean, to connect the `QPushButton` from class `a` with `method_1` in class `B`. Hope you can help me.

### ------ EDIT ------

I had to make some modifications to my code and I delete the `button` method, and I put it in a `toolbar`. So now I have this:

```
class A(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
    #A lot of stuff in here

    self.toolbar = QToolBar(self)
    self.btn = QPushButton()
    self.toolbar.addWidget(self.btn)
    self.connect(self.btn, SIGNAL("clicked()"), B().method_1)

class B(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    #Another stuff in here too

  def method_1(self):
    pass
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Normal.

Look at your code:

```
def Button(self):
    self.btn = QPushButton()
    self.connect(self.btn, SIGNAL("clicked()"), B().method_1)
```

After self.connect() is called, B objet no longer exists.
Therefore, when you click on your button, the handler B.method_1 does not exist anymore. 
Try passing B in parameter of A.Button() method.

```
def Button(self, B_class):
        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.connect(self.btn, SIGNAL("clicked()"), B_class.method_1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One question, if the button is in `__init__` in class `A` , do i have to write: `def __init__(self, B_class)`?

Comment: I am asking that because I had to make some modifications. I edited the question to show what i´ve done.

Comment: You can do that. But I strongly recommend to have a separate init() in which you can pass the object B in parameter. Make your code as pythonic as possible and the most readable.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to create an object of B in class A:

```
self.b = B()
```

then you can use this object's method_1 in `A.__init__`:

```
self.connect(self.btn, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.b.method_1)
```

If you do not want to create a new instance of B, you can instead add an argument to the constructor:

```
class A(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, b):
        # ...code...
        self.connect(self.btn, SIGNAL("clicked()"), b.method_1)
```